# How to reset lazy after screen rotation

Tags: android, kotlin

Based on my theme I use different layouts in my app, so I cant use `DataBinding` in my use case because this would clutter my whole code with functions like following:

```
fun getCVAnswer() : CardView {
    return when (ThemeManager.themeStyle()) {
        ThemeManager.Style.Modern -> return (binding as MviGameActivityModern).cvAnswer1
        ThemeManager.Style.Round -> return (binding as MviGameActivityRound).cvAnswer1
        ...
    }
}
```

So I want to use an alternative solution, all my styles have the same layouts and same ids, so I can do following that works in all styles:

```
 private val cvAnswer1 by lazy { findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cvAnswer1) }
```

**Question**

After screen rotation, I will leak the activity and `cvAnswer1` has the wrong view in it (the one from my activity before rotation). Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't u use Android Kotlin Extension here?

Comment: You mean the syntactic imports? Because I would have to use different imports based on the style... Same problem as I have with the `DataBinding`...

Comment: I have similar requirement and provided my solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294183/lazy-variable-with-reset .